# Specifying custom screen resolution in Selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screen-resolution

As mentioned in the below blog, we can modify screen resolution during selenium test runs. 
http://blog.testingbot.com/2013/03/15/screen-resolution-option-now-available-for-all-selenium-tests

Tried the below code(as mentioned in "https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config"), but not setting the specified resolution. Is this still not available for Selenium?

```
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();    
dc.setCapability("screen-resolution","1280x1024");
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sauce Labs != Selenium

Sauce labs use that capability to provision you a VM with the desired resolution, it's not a capability that Selenium itself knows about.

**Selenium is not capable of modifying your desktop resolution!**

If you want to modify your browser size in Selenium so that it matches a specific resolution you can do a:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768))
```

The above is not supported with Opera driver, so instead you would need to do:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera()
capabilities.setCapability("opera.arguments", "-screenwidth 1024 -screenheight 768")
```

While setting the browser size is not the same as setting the screen resolution, it should for all intents and purposes meet your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Selenium is a browser automation framework, its job is to drive a browser, not to automate your system. I don't think that a functionality such as setting a screen resolution will ever be implemented in Selenium. Setting resolution has simply nothing to do with browser automation.

I am not sure why do you want to change the resolution... How about just changing the size of your browser window? That's something you could do if you are testing responsive-designed pages.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
```

Comment: The website I'm testing is [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).  The markup changes from large to small breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `DesiredCapabilities` is to tell the Grid where to run your tests.

So, if there is a remote node connected to the Grid with the resolution you specified `1280x1024`, the test will run on that node. If any other nodes do not have this resolution, the test will not run on those nodes.

If you do not specify a screen resolution in the `DesiredCapabilities`, the test will run on nodes with any resolution.

This feature of Selenium does not actually change or modify a testing node's screen resolution. It only tells the Grid on which nodes to run or not run your tests.

Comment: But they mentioned, we can modify/adjust the screen-resolution on Windows, Linux and Mac..? [link](http://blog.testingbot.com/2013/03/15/screen-resolution-option-now-available-for-all-selenium-tests).

Comment: Poor choice of words on their part I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in doing is probably best done through native java code rather than through Selenium which is a web browser testing framework.

The question of changing the resolution through Java was addressed in another thread here on StackOverflow.

[swing - Change screen resolution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225113/change-screen-resolution-in-java)

Although I am curious as to why you are trying to do this, since you didn't explain that above and may lead to a better response from the community.  =)

Comment: We just ran into the same problem in our test automation infrastructure. The problem is Windows defaults to a very small screen size(I assume 800x600), and then if the website under test doesn't support such a small resolution without overlapping UI elements, and the browser will fail some tests for items that are no longer visible.