# RemoteWebDriver Chrome window size cap

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I am unable to resize a RemoteWebDriver's window size to a width greater than around 1040 pixels. The hub is running on a Red Hat VM with the node running on the Windows host machine with Google Chrome. My Selenium framework is in Java.

The following methods have been tested:
1) driver.manage().window().setSize()
2) Adding a "--window-size" switch to DesiredCapabilities' options
3) Resizing the window with Javascript window.open() command via JavaScriptExecutor

Each of these methods resize the driver's window, but not any larger than 1040 pixels. When I run Selenium tests locally on the hub with a Firefox WebDriver, I do not experience this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome willnot resize to the size that is larger than your current resolution. If you need to resize your browser, please try with firefox,

or

resize your current resolution by java [Change screen resolution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225113/change-screen-resolution-in-java)