# How to change laptop screen resolution in java?

Tags: java, screen, resolution

Is there a way to right a program in java that when I run it, it changes the screen resolution of my laptop? Not just the resolution of the program running but of the entire laptop. There is a separate game that I need to run in 720 and it's a pain to change it everytime, it'd be easier if I was just able to run this program to change it. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225113/change-screen-resolution-in-java See this thread

Comment: Is it important that it's Java? A language like AutoHotkey that's designed for scripting these kinds of OS-specific shortcut might be a lot simpler here.

Comment: I'll check out AutoHotKey, thanks! I only know java and c++ but prefer java so I thought that'd be the easiest!

Comment: And, jhort, thanks for that link! I'll check that out later, but for now it seems this AutoHotKey is much simpler for what I need!